# How to check whether text file is encoded in UTF-8?

Tags: c++, utf-8

How to check whether text file is encoded in UTF-8 in C++?

Comment: Do you want to add it to your own program, or use an existing program?

Comment: The correct answer would be "It's impossible. So don't check at all. Always assumes it's the default. All other encoding shall be deprecated, they are almost unused today for textual files interchange."

Answer (score 5):

Try to read it as UTF-8 and see if UTF-8 encoding is broken or not and if not, if there are valid Unicode points only.

But still there's no guarantee the file is in UTF-8 or ASCII or something else. How would you interpret a file containing a single byte, the letter `A`? ASCII? UTF-8? Other? Likewise, what if the file starts with the [`BOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) by sheer luck but isn't really UTF-8 or isn't intended to be UTF-8?

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx) may be of interest.

Answer (score 4):

You can never know for sure that any piece of binary data was *intended* to represent UTF-8. However, you can always check if it *can* be interpreted as UTF-8. The simplest way would be to just try and convert it (say to UTF-32) and see if you get no errors. If all you need is the validation, then you can do the same thing without actually writing the output. (You'll need to write this yourself, but it's easy.)

Note that it is crucial for security reasons to abort the conversion entirely at the first error, and not try to "recover" somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to UTF-16. If you get no errors, then it is very likely UTF-8.
But not matter what you do, it is still a best guess.